# AVAudioNode gets deallocated immediately

Tags: core-audio, avaudioengine

I can not create and attach `AVAudioNode` to `AVAudioEngine` as it gets deallocated immediately.

I've created a subclass of `AVAudioNode`, added `deinit` and during debug it was triggered immediately.

I've tried to log this in console and got `<uninitialized>` response.

```
po AVAudioNode()
```

On the contrary, it works with `AVAudioMixerNode`

```
po AVAudioMixerNode()
```

I'm not storing it weakly. I set it as a strong property in my class/actor.

```
class MyClass {
    let node = AVAudioNode()
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    
    fun foo() {
        print(node) // This will crash the app
        engine.attach(node) // As well as this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVAudioNode is defined as an interface.

```
@interface AVAudioNode : NSObject {
```

Interfaces are not concrete; you do not instantiate them. They are for inheritance purposes only.

AVAudioMixerNode is a concrete class that implements the AVAudioNode interface. That is why you see it in the console when you po it.

```
open class AVAudioMixerNode : AVAudioNode, AVAudioMixing {
```